# Can I browse the Windows App Store outside of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

Is there a way to browse the Windows App Store outside of Windows 8?

I want to be able to look at the collection of apps in the store outside of windows, similar to how I can browse through the Apple App Store outside of iTunes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows App store can be access from their [App Store Web Page](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/)

Comment: Dang beat me to it :P

Comment: @KronoS slowpoke :P

Answer (score 10):

[I asked a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12618684/325251).

<s>While there is currently no official Windows 8 app directory, I came across the website [Windows8Apps](http://www.windows8apps.com/) (though not perfect) that comes close.</s> Update: As @kgander42 has mentioned, there is now a [official search page for Windows 8 Apps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search#q=&s=Store).

Another alternative is to [use Google or Bing to search for apps related to a keyword (for example, site:apps.microsoft.com foursquare) using the site:apps.microsoft.com operator.](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-quickly-find-if-siteservice-is.html)

Comment: How about windows phone store? `site:....microsoft.com`?

Comment: @EndyTjahjono the question is about searching for apps not just anything else on microsoft.com!

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has finally provided [a page to browse their store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search#q=&s=Store).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website which allows you to browse the Windows Store on any Browser or Operating System:

**[MetroStore Scanner](http://metrostore.preweb.sk/)**