# How can I see most popular apps in the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I browse the Windows App Store outside of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/490202/can-i-browse-the-windows-app-store-outside-of-windows-8)

I can see best apps on Android by going to:
https://play.google.com/store/apps

How do browse the most popular apps of Windows 8 ("metro" apps) on a desktop running Windows 7?