# How to access Windows 8 Store from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I browse the Windows App Store outside of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/490202/can-i-browse-the-windows-app-store-outside-of-windows-8)

Is there a way for me to access the Windows 8 store at http://apps.microsoft.com/ from Windows 7? I can get a direct link to an [application's entry in Windows Store](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-GB/app/skitch/95a8df2f-f779-4034-a995-82d8e723b246), but I cannot browse the store.

Going to http://apps.microsoft.com/ results in

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browse the store with this website:

**MetroStore Scanner**

http://metrostore.preweb.sk/

Comment: Simple, brilliant, it works!

Comment: Server not found!

Comment: @marcolopes you can now browse the store: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search#q=&s=Store MS changed this now.